# Web Browser in browser applet using Java

Tags: java, html, browser, applet

There are Java standalone browsers like http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/.
Is there a way to make and run such browser in web applet?

Comment: A browser, in an applet, in a browser.  Horrid usability!  For the sake of the end user, am hoping you are unable to achieve this.  Instead see [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) or [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Andrew Would this direct browser away from Applet?

Comment: I am sure it is possible; why would it not be?

Comment: @tucuxi i know little about Java programming so that's why i ask.

Comment: *"Would this direct browser away from Applet?"*  Did you follow the links, read the instructions about what each does?  One will, one won't - depending on parameter.

Comment: What exactly is the content you wish to show?  YouTube, your own help files..?

Comment: Ok, i understand if i won't specify target then page will be loaded by browser in same window. I'd like to operate on different webpages (and domains) that's why the idea of Browser in Browser came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) is a Java library that can be used in Java Applets. You can develop your own Java Applet and use JxBrowser's Browser component in it to display web pages. More information about how to use JxBrowser in Java Applets you can find at http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/JxBrowser-PGuide.html#applet